# Invertible sheaf isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(div (s))$ but $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $s \in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ we now that all such sections is in bijective correspondence to linear polynomials $a_0 + a_1 x$, so we take section $s$ wich corresponding to constant $1$. Divisor of such section is trivial (there is no zeros and poles), and Vakhil 14.2.E say that $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{O}(div (s))$ for any invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ and it section $s$. So 
$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(div(s)) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\text{trivial divisor}) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$$ 
but it is definitely wrong. Where is mistake?

Comment: You need a *homogeneous* polynomial of degree $1$ for your section. You need to think about what makes sense on $\Bbb P^1$. :)

Comment: You are totally right, it was not very smart question :) Thank you!

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you explain me such thing (don't want to create another question): let $f \in \mathcal{O}(div (s))_{X,p}$ then $sf \in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}?$. Example $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, $s = x_0$, $p = (0,1)$, $f = \frac{1}{x_0}$. So it seems like morphism $t \mapsto ts$ is of type $\mathcal{O}(div(s))_{X,p} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ right?